# java servlet form fileupload broken in Internet Explorer with target="_blank"

Tags: java, forms, file-upload, servlet-3.0

My java file upload servlet is broken (InputStream is empty) in Internet Explorer 11 and Edge when I add target="_blank" to the form. It's working perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox.

FileUploadServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/FileUploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*50,
                 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100)
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            if(part.getName().equals("file")) {
                System.out.println("stream length: " + part.getInputStream().available());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working form:

```
<form action="FileUploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Broken form:

```
<form action="FileUploadServlet" method="post" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I get the form with target="_blank" also running in ie11?

Comment: This seems unrelated to server-side technologies. I'm looking at the same issue, and Edge simply doesn't send the contents of the file. I guess our best bet is to open a bug report with Microsoft.